# The constructor is undefined with java programming

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a constructor that input a user automatically whenever you run my program and if no user in the database, then input admin.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "fmsusers")
public class UsersVO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "userEmail")
    private String userEmail;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Transient
    private String passwordConfirm;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber; 

    @Column(name = "Enabled", length = 1)
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToManyenter code here
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<RolesVO> rolesVO;


    public static List<UsersVO> usersInit() throws Exception {

        List<UsersVO> initUsers = new ArrayList<UsersVO>();
        try {
                    initUsers.add(new UsersVO(1,"admin@gmail.com", "$2a$10$PrI5Gk9L.tSZiW9FXhTS8O8Mz9E97k2FZbFvGFFaSsiTUIl.TCrFu", "$2a$10$PrI5Gk9L.tSZiW9FXhTS8O8Mz9E97k2FZbFvGFFaSsiTUIl.TCrFu",
                            "Claude", "Kabayiza","0783240776", true));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return initUsers;
    }
}
```

The constructor UsersVO(int, String, String, String, String, String, String, boolean) is undefined

Comment: Is anything unclear in the error message ?

Comment: Can you have a look into your `UsersVO` class and check which constructors are defined there? I think this error message is not really cryptic, its straight forward. If you don't find the *bug*, post that class here.

Answer (score 0):

You havent defined a Constructor with the parametes u put in, so Java just knows the Default Constructor without any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified any constructor with the parameters you want to persist. All your class has is default constructor inherited from parent Object. Use lombok to define @NoArgsConstructor, @RequiredArgsConstructor, @AllArgsConstructor explicitly as you require. @RequiredArgsConstructor --> non-initialized final fields get a parameter, as well as any fields that are marked as @NonNull that aren't initialized where they are declared.